# Merge two lists in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, merge

I get this function to merge two lists in Haskell:

```
merge :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
merge xs     []     = xs
merge []     ys     = ys
merge (x:xs) (y:ys) = x : y : merge xs ys
```

but I want this function `merge :: ([a],[a]) -> [a]`, how do I make this change?

Answer (score 4):

You could reuse the `merge` function to make it work for tuples of lists as follows:

```hs
merge :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
merge xs     []     = xs
merge []     ys     = ys
merge (x:xs) (y:ys) = x : y : merge xs ys

mergeTuples :: ([a], [a]) -> [a]
mergeTuples (xs, ys) = merge xs ys
```

Answer (score 4):

There is an [uncurry](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:uncurry) function, which can be helpful in such situations. Quote:

> uncurry converts a curried function to a function on pairs.

In this case, we can use it to derive `merge'` from `merge`:

```
merge' :: ([a], [a]) -> [a]
merge' = uncurry merge

merge' ([1],[2]) == [1, 2] --> True
```

Answer (score 3):

You change

```
merge1 :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
merge1    xs     []   = xs
merge1    []     ys   = ys
merge1  (x:xs) (y:ys) = x : y : merge1 xs ys
```

to

```
merge2 :: ([a], [a]) -> [a]
merge2    ( xs, [] )  = xs
merge2    ( [], ys )  = ys
merge2   (x:xs, y:ys) = x : y : merge2 (xs, ys)
```

`merge1` is known as a "curried" function, and `merge2` as "uncurried".

The functions `curry` and `uncurry` go between the two forms by packaging/unpackaging the arguments as needed while calling the given function:

```
curry   f  x y  = f (x,y)
uncurry g (x,y) = g  x y
```

Thus `merge1 = curry merge2` and `merge2 = uncurry merge1`, but you have to actually define at least one of them to implement the actual functionality.